# How to change the details based on the selected item in list view

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i have a listview with some items, the list view is bind to an list of objects. When i select a item from the list view, i want to appear some buttons and TextBlock down from the listview and when i click on another item in listview i want other buttons and TextBlock to be shown. I think it has something to do with user control because i know that having all the buttons and TextBlocks one over another and just make them visible and hidden will not solve my problem nicely.

How can i make this nice?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're asking how to create a Master-Detail view in WPF.  IF that is the case, there are a lot of examples out there that you can review and use, depending on your exact scenario.  Here are just a couple options:

1. [MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/01/19/create-wpf-master-detail-ui-using-data-sources-window-object-datasource.aspx)
2. [Code Project using MVVM](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/332615/WPF-Master-Details-MVVM-Application)
3. [MSDN Video](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dd239277.aspx)